# Flowplayer shows 3 dots in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

I'm using the commercial version of flowplayer, the player works fine in FF and IE, but in Chrome when I jump in the stream 3 loading white dots appear and don't go away although the video finished loading

```
<div id="player" class="avPlayer-wrap customFlowPlayer">
    <video preload="none">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
    </video>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#player").flowplayer({
            playlist: [
                [
                    { mp4:  "video.mp4" },
                    { ogg:  "video.ogv" }
                ]
            ],
            swf: "//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.6/commercial/flowplayer.swf",
            key: '${playerKey}'
        });
    });
</script>
```